# Installing Lync Group Chat Server

Tags: lync

I have an enterprise pool deployment of Lync 2010.  Can I install the group chat server components on the servers that make up my front end servers as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to technet, you should never collocate the Group Chat service.  See link:  [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd425201(office.13).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd425201%28office.13%29.aspx)

Comment: I notice this link is actually for OCS 2007 R2 -- I cannot find the relevant documentation for Lync that would confirm this, but I would strongly believe that requirement has not changed from 2007R2.